# Is it possible to create, and set VBA Dictionaries outside of a Function(s)?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm creating several custom functions within Excel VBA that require the use of 3 dictionaries.

These dictionaries do not change once they are set.

Right now each dictionary is created inside each function.

I would prefer to clean it up, set the dictionary once and just reference it within the functions.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any documentation about this subject.

Comment: You can create a global variable that would be accessible from any module or object. Or you can create a persistent object class that would hold the dictionaries (and possibly provide a nicer interface).

Comment: While this might seem a compelling idea, you very, VERY likely don't *need* any global dictionary object. Global state paves the road to unmaintainable code. A global object's reference can be `Set` by any code, anywhere. Depending on what you need it for (too little info to tell), encapsulating the state in an object, and passing that object as a parameter to the functions that need it, is most definitely a much better idea. Are the functions completely independent or they're in the same call graph?

Comment: Use ADODB instead of dictionaries. They can be saved to disk with one function call. See an example here https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/cutexe-removes-specified-lines-from-top.html and documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-properties-methods-and-events?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Noodles that's making quite a wild assumption about what the OP needs a global dictionary for.

Comment: @Noddles I'm using dictionaries to take advantage of the .Exists method.

Comment: That is almost certainly the wrong approach. When you add a key the act of adding automatically does an `.exists`. So when you do it you are making 2 function calls at worse, and checking if the key exists twice. In programming we do something and check if it works (if we care). So you add your key and see if it worked or not by checking if there an error in adding. See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/dedupexe-removes-duplicate-lines-from.html for a sample.

Comment: @Noddles I'm not aware of a better method to store specific strings that I can query against. I'm adding a specific set of strings to the dictionary so that I can query against it from random sets of data. My understanding is that using dictionaries to check if a specific string exists works well for others in similar situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for global variables, which are variables surviving in memory over all the execution of the program.

Practically:

```
Dim myDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary '<-- on top of module, outside of any macro/function. This makes the variable LOCAL to the module (i.e. accessible all over the subs and functions of the module)
'Alternatively (one or the other)
Public myDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary '<-- the variable is GLOBAL to all the program.

Sub init() '<-- initialize your dictionary once
    Set myDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary
    myDictionary.add "Apples", 50
    myDictionary.add "Bananas", 40
End Sub

Function a() As Integer
    ...
    a = myDictionary("Apples") '<-- use your dictionary when you want
    ...
End Function
```

You can put a call to `init` inside the `ThisWorkbook.Open` event, so that as soon as your workbook is open, you will have your dictionaries living all over the execution.

Comment: Except `Dim` is always local/private. A global variable would be `Public`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Dim works for the module where you declare them, Global is for all the modules. Am I wrong? thought you shouldn't teach him using global variables but passing parameters to the function Matteo.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon true both for `Dim` and the comment you wrote under the question. Will specify this in the answer.

Comment: Absolutely agreed (see my own comment about global state under the OP) - except both answers here are talking about "global variables", and none actually contain anything global, which... feels weird.

Comment: @Damian, though I generally tend to agree with you, and that we should avoid global variables when possible, here it rather seems that OP wants to create a sort of `Const`. This is provided by other languages (e.g. in Java you would say `static`), but VBA doesn't allow `Const` of type `Dictionary`. I'd say is a workaround, I would try to avoid it but sometimes we can't really do much different.

Comment: Well I guess this is the closest way thought

Comment: @MatteoNNZ If a variable has a life over the life of the program, and it is frequently used **it should be a global**. EG hWnds are used 10s of times per second in a GUI program. People that avoid globals altogether tend to write twisted code - ie they maintain state in a slow way (eg hiding the global variable as a registry key). One doesn't want to fill the global namespace with unimportant stuff but we do with important stuff like hWnds. Knowing how to scope variables is important. Local scope means a local variable, global scope means a global variables.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
'declare some global variables to hold your dictionaries
Dim dict1 as object, dict2 as object, dict3 as object

'a sub to create and populate the dictionaries
sub InitDicts()
    If dict1 is nothing then

        'create and populate dicts 1-3

    End if
end sub

'*** functions which use the dictionaries ***

Function ThisFunction()
    InitDicts
    'use dicts
end function

Function ThatFunction()
    InitDicts
    'use dicts
end function
```

Comment: `Dim` is always local/private. A global variable would be `Public`.

Comment: When I InitDict within each function, I get a Compile Error: Sub or Function Not Defined.

Comment: Did you create the sub, and is it call `InitDict`, or `InitDicts` ?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - guess I should have said "module-level variables"

Comment: Sorry I'm such a pedantic annoyance ;-)